# How to use contents of a list to interpolate in markup as variables?

Tags: emmet

Using emmet, and given a list of strings, how do you interpolate them into the expanded emmet markup?

This is hard to word, so let me show an example:

I'd like to turn this:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

into:

```
<p id="foo">foo</p>
<p id="bar">bar</p>
<p id="baz">baz</p>
```

by selecting the list and using an emmet expression like:

```
p#<token>{<token>}
```

I just can't remember what `<token>` is. And I can't find it in the documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, through the suggested questions on SO! The token is `$#` as per https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#controlling-output-position

I remember it was in the docs, just not under an intuitive name.